# Probability question involving independent events and expected value

Tags: probability, expectation

I am working on the following problem:

> A company sends products in boxes of $12$ units each. Before shipping, $3$ random units from each box are tested. If any of the $3$ are defective, the entire box is held back. Each unit has an independent probability of $0.2$ of being defective. What percentage of shipments are held back?

My thinking is that regardless of the size of the shipment, the chance of at least one unit being defective is $1-0.8^3 = 0.488$ ($1$ minus the probability of all $3$ units passing the test), this would lead me to believe that the answer is $48.8\%$.

Is this solution correct? I'm a bit uncertain since my answer is independent of the shipment size, but I can't find any flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: I think your answer looks fine.

Comment: You can calculate $$\sum_{k=1}^{12} {12 \choose k}\cdot 0.2^k\cdot 0.8^{12-k}\cdot \left(1-\frac{{k \choose 0}\cdot {{12-k} \choose 3}}{{12 \choose 3}}\right)$$ as well. The binomial term calculates the probability that  $k$ of the $1$2 units in the box are defect. And then you calculate the probability that you choose at least 1 defect unit out of $k$ defect units in a box. The result is also $48.8\%$. The calculation is time-consuming, but maybe more comprehensible.

Comment: There is no flaw in reasoning that the probability the sample passes inspection is independent of shipment size, because the probability of each item passes is independent of every other.

Comment: @GrahamKemp If you referring to my comment, I did not say that there is any flaw. I just wanted to look from another side on this problem.

Comment: @calculus No, it was referring to Alex's post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you are correct. The probability *does not* depend on the size of the box.

If you are unsure about the intuition, consider the following equivalent problem :

> Take three coins and toss them. What is the probability of getting 3
> "Heads"? (of course, it is $1/8$).
> Now, what if the coins were first drawn from a box containing 12
> coins? from a box containing 1000 coins?
>
> **Answer**: always $1/8$, regardless of the size of the box!